# A part of speech 'kind of'

Tags: parts-of-speech

> We kind of fought with each other.

What part of speech is 'kind of' in the sentence above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sentence the phrase is acting as an *adverb*.  It modifies *fight* to indicate the word is only an example of a generic conflict.

The exchange may have only been a very loud exchange of words rather than punch to the nose.  See:

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/kind%20of)